# Add an action button with a unique CSS class to WooCommerce my account orders

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

Here is my function for adding an option to my orders page:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'add_my_account_my_orders_custom_action', 10, 2 );
function add_my_account_my_orders_custom_action( $actions, $order ) {
    $action_slug = 'specific_name';

    $actions[$action_slug] = array(
        'url'  => home_url('/the_action_url/'),
        'name' => 'The Button Text',
    );
    return $actions;
}
```

My question is this : How Can I add my custom CSS to ONLY my newly created option

(There are 3 other buttons except my button that I do not want to change their style and all 4 of them have same class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$action_slug = 'specific_name';` will automatically add this as a class to the button.

Then you can use the following selector

```css
.woocommerce-account table.account-orders-table .specific_name {
    color: red;
}
```

To apply CSS specifically or to overwrite existing CSS

---

To do the reverse and remove certain classes for this particular button, you need to overwrite the template file [/myaccount/orders.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/orders.php) in addition to your existing code

- This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php`.

Replace line 69 - 71 @version 3.7.0

```php
foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
}
```

With

```php
foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited                                   
    // Compare
    if ( $key == 'specific_name' ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';                                         
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: did not work . this is the class of the buttons : class="bgSecColor-wpyarpanel-wpyarpanel wColor-wpyarpanel sendFormProfileWpyarPanel wpyarpanel-m-0"

Comment: also 'specific_name' is outside of the class

Comment: @Kingnima Sorry, but these are not default classes present in WooCommerce, 
none of this is mentioned in your question. No one can guess that your setup is different

Comment: thanks for the answer . tested with default theme and worked !

Answer (score 1):

When displaying the buttons on the frontend, the action key is assigned as a classname, so you can assign different CSS based on action key like this:

```
.shop_table .button.specific_name {
 color: #fff;
}
```